# Seleccionar total de prestamos de hombres y mujeres por fecha en SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Quiero realizar una consulta donde teniendo una tabla de personas con id, nombre y genero y una tabla de prestamos con su id y fecha, pueda mostrar una vista tipo:

```
Año     | Mes | Masculino | Femenino | Total
2021      11        3           2        5
2022      6         4           2        6
.         .         .           .        .
Totales |           7           4        11
```

Donde la celda masculino y femenino tienen el total del personas con prestamo en ese tiempo, la ultima columna los totales por fila y la ultima fila los totales de las columnas.

Hasta ahora se me ha ocurrido este codigo:

```
select extract(year from p.fecha) as año, extract(month from p.fecha) as mes, count(case when d.genero='M' then 1 end) as masculino, count(case when d.genero='F' then 1 end) as femenino, (masculino+femenino) as total
from prestamo p inner join deudor d on p.iddeudor = d.id
order by extract(year from p.fecha), extract(month from p.fecha)
```

Pero me da el error ""FEMENINO": identificador no válido"  y sin la columna de total, me da el error "not a single-group group function", y la ultima fila con los totales de las columnas la verdad es que no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

¿Que puedo hacer en este caso? Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: (masculino+femenino) as total lo reemplazas por count(*). Luego al final de la query agrupa por año y mes

Comment: @Yussef Muchas gracias, funcionó!  Sabría también como hacer la última fila con la sumas de las columnas? De nuevo gracias

Comment: count(*) as total, no da el total??

Comment: "Sabría también como hacer la última fila con la sumas de las columnas? De nuevo gracias" <- no, esa no es funcionalidad de sql.. tal vez, alguna herramienta lo agregue por si misma, pero no es funcionalidad standard. Podrias simularlo usando un union y agregando otra consulta que sumarize...

Comment: @Yussef si da el total de las filas en la última columna, me faltaría el total de las columnas en la última fila